# Incorrect last activity timestamps on dynamically loaded new questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps, live-refresh

If you hang around on the front page a lot, after a while you will see this bar:

[image]

I click it, and a few new/updated questions pop in:

[image]

But why does it say that question was changed in 2011 last? It was changed right now!

A quick refresh of the page confirms it:

[image]

Comment: I noted this on meta today. Not only it shows old timestamp but also it shows the previous person who updated it before the latest one. So the timestamp is also displayed of that second last person's edit.

Comment: @hims056: I actually assumed that it displays the whole "state" of the question from the time before the update that triggered the notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug that slipped in to a recent refactoring.  The next build will be rolling out here shortly.