# Wrong user information about the recent activity on question?

Tags: bug, live-refresh, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect last activity timestamps on dynamically loaded new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156461/incorrect-last-activity-timestamps-on-dynamically-loaded-new-questions)

When someone edits/answers on a post then recent activity doesn't show the right name of the user who really interact recently with that post.

[image]

I have answered the question on the top in screenshot but it is showing up the name who interact the last time with post while in recent activity there should be my name, if I'm getting the system right?

Also the second post has the same problem other user just posted an answer there and it showing up the time and name which interacted with it last.

So is it a bug or its how system is working?